# Scala: single abstract methods without a parameter

Tags: scala, single-abstract-method

With SAM types, we can have:

```
trait Sam {
  def foo(i: Int): String
}

val sam : Sam = _.toString
```

What if my abstract method doesn't have a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda with an empty argument list like this:

```
trait Sam {
  def foo(): String
}

val sam : Sam = () => "hello"
```

You can not use `_` notation because there's no way to define a zero-argument function with `_`.

This won't work if `foo` is defined as `def foo: String` instead (i.e. if it doesn't have a parameter list) because SAM-conversion only applies if the single method has exactly one parameter list.

Comment: thanks. Sadly `toString` which initiated this problem is an example of `def foo: String` so it looks like I cannot use SAMs with it.

Comment: @Mathsnoob `toString` in your example is in the implementation, not the method being defined, that's not a problem. And for those `def foo: String` cases, you don't get SAM-conversion for free, but an equivalent can be easily added.